# CSS and jQuery universal tree menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create universal tree menu, with `ul` `li` `ul`. And I've made something like this using just CSS:

CSS

```
.category-list {
}

.category-list li ul {
  display: none;
}

.category-list li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="category-list">
  <li>
    <a href="" title="">Category 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" title="">Sub-category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Sub-cateagory 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Sub-category 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="" title="">Category 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" title="">Sub-category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Sub-category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="" title="">Sub-category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/usz9ycmj/1/

--
And I want to make similar effect, but on click, so just current clicked tab displays its parent content. 
Even more important for me is the ability to add and remove class on specific action:

```
.category-list li.current -- while is currently clicked (active)

.category-list li -- removed while different li is clicked (active)
```

Just, the trigger `li` has two different states for active and inactive. It changes the colors and arrow from closed to opened to give it a look of a tree menu - I bet You get the point.

I want the simple jquery code, if someone has time to help. feel welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working code.

Please read the comments and let me know if something not clear.

```js
// listen to the click event
var all_items = $('.category-list>li').click(function(event) {
  // stop the propagation - this will abort the function when you click on the child li
  event.stopPropagation();
  var elm = $(this);
  // remove the class from all the items
  all_items.not(elm).removeClass('current');
  // add class if it's not the current item
  elm.toggleClass('current', !elm.is('.current'));
});
```

```css
.category-list {
}

.category-list li ul {
  display: none;
}

.category-list li.current > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<ul class="category-list">
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="">Category 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Sub-category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Sub-category 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Sub-category 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" title="">Category 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Sub-category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Sub-category 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="">Sub-category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsbin.com/tocewe/edit?html,css,js

Comment: It works great and is super simple to understand. Thank You Mosh.
Please tell me, if this will work with every browser including old IE ?

And I am wondering, what is the easiest way to add slide down, slide up animation for sub-categories ?

Comment: I'm glad to hear;) Good luck.

Comment: You suppose to work on old (defined `old`) IE browsers, just use jQuery version 1 because in version 2 they dropped the support [IE8 -](https://jquery.com/browser-support/). To add slide animation, you can use  **css3 transitions**. If you need to support old IEs, you can use jQuery [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Comment: Ok, I think I will figure out the css3 transition. How to add to Your jquery code 1 more function: after second click on the same category, how to implement closing? (I mean first click opens the subcategory, second click on this same category closes it).

Comment: Thank You one more and last time :)